# Proper way to init a UIView with .xib and backing class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, initialization

I have some custom created UIViews that use .xib files for layout, and backing classes for extra setup.  I create these classes using alloc/init and calling loadNibNamed in my custom init method but in doing so was causing memory leak.  Someone pointed out that the alloc portion actually created a self object that was leaking so I adjusted my init method to this one:

```
- (id)init 
{
    [self autorelease];
    self = [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AssignmentView" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject] retain];
    [self setupBranding];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
    [tapRecognizer release];

    return self;
}
```

However, now when I run analyze code I get this warning "Returning 'self' while it is not set to the result of '[(super or self) init...]'".  So my question is what is the correct way for doing custom UIViews with a backing class?

Since it was asked I'd used this above code like this:

```
AssignmentView * assignmentView = [[AssignmentView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:assignmentView];
```

Comment: Generally, if you load a view from an xib, you should be loading it through `loadNibNamed` in whatever class you're creating it in and then setting it up in its `awakeFromNib` method, not even touching `init`. This has been my experience, anyway. Could you perhaps add some code where you are instantiating the view, and your `awakeFromNib` method?

Comment: I think you would just add `self = [super init]` at the top of your method. Paul is right though, in that you normally aren't doing the nib loading internally.

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying to avoid the whole loadNibNamed and just use [[MyView alloc] init] instead, but if I have to re-work that and instead use the loadNibNamed then I guess I have to.  I don't have an awakeFromNib method but everything in the init would go there.

Answer (score 19):

Get the view from -`[NSBundle loadNibNamed:owner:options:],` then set its frame to match your view's bounds. Generally you'll also want to make the view in the nib resize when its parent view is resized.

We've got a UIView category with these additions:

```
- (UIView *)viewFromNib
{
    Class class = [self class];
    NSString *nibName = NSStringFromClass(class);
    NSArray *nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:nil];
    UIView *view = [nibViews objectAtIndex:0];
    return view;
}


- (void)addSubviewFromNib
{
    UIView *view = [self viewFromNib];
    view.frame = self.bounds;
    [self addSubview:view];
}
```

Then our -initWithFrame: method looks like this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self addSubviewFromNib];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Just make sure the nib has the same name as the class for this to work.

Comment: Another interesting solution.  I like this as I don't have to change how I'm already using my views

Comment: I know this is old, but this is a great solution, and exactly what I was hoping to do.

Answer (score 7):

Would you consider using the convenience constructor style?

```
+ (AssignmentView *)assignmentView
{
    AssignmentView *result = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AssignmentView" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
    [result setupBranding];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:)];
    [result addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
    [tapRecognizer release];

    return result;
}
```

It gives you the flexibility you seem to need when construct your view, but doesn't cause a memory leak or warnings.

Comment: Interesting, I'll give this a shot.